# heroku public ip listed on spamhaus.org

Tags: hosting, heroku, ip, shared-hosting

I'm hosting a client site on heroku. The client is pointing their custom-domain-name (A-record) to one of the public IPs of heroku. Now, my client contacted me and complained that their emails are being rejected by one of their biggest clients due to a sbl-listing of the same IPs on www.spamhaus.org ( http://www.spamhaus.org/sbl/sbl.lasso?query=SBL107993 ). Now the spammer is some url-shortener and has nothing to do with my clients business.

I did a lot of searches on google, but found little. Just that the problems have to do with shared IPs. But what is the solution? And as heroku is hosting big applcations there must be others having the same issue? Or is there one simple trick to solve this?

Cheers
Nick

Comment: Speak to Heroku support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the same problem, no simple trick here. Here is Heroku's support response to the matter :

> We're working with Spamhaus to get our
>   IPs removed from their lists. They've
>   proven to be very difficult to work
>   with and don't always remove IPs even
>   when complying with their terms.
>
> The root of the problem is with mail
>   providers having misconfigured SPAM
>   filters. You'll want to follow up with
>   any mail providers that are flagging
>   your emails as SPAM and ask them to
>   adjust their filters as to not flag
>   legitimate emails as SPAM. We'll
>   continue to work with Spamhaus to get
>   these IPs removed but it's best to
>   make this a two front effort.
>
> As a work around if you use hostname
>   SSL we'll provide you with a new
>   hostname to point your domain to. This
>   will disassociate your domain with the
>   3 listed IPs.

**Reference**

Our link from Spamhaus : http://www.spamhaus.org/SBL/sbl.lasso?query=SBL107992

**Summary**

- See if your recipient has mis-configured SPAM filters
- Wait for Heroku to fix the problem

**Update**

Heroku support says it may take weeks to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general problem that affects many hosting companies. Spammers are probably using Heroku to send spam, and have tarnished Heroku's IP address space. It will indeed take weeks to resolve this, because Heroku will have to prove to Spamhaus that they have put in place policies and procedures to limit spam.

You might suggest that Heroku review the Wikipedia content regarding outbound spam control: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-spam_techniques#Outbound_spam_protection

It's a complex issue, particularly for PaaS providers, who are of course trying to make hosting of apps automatic and easy - something that appeals to spammers.